# Conditional access blocks onedrive from within another app

Tags: azure

Something I can't seem to wrap my head around:

Enabled CA for Exchange Online and Sharepoint online to be accesible only from Intune compliant devices, works great.

On my iPhone I downloaded the Sharepoint app, logged in, and that works great. Same for the Onedrive app.

But when I try access either Sharepoint or Onedrive from another app (PDF-Expert to edit PDF's), it gives an error message:

> Login failed, please try again later.

When I look at the user sign-ins, I see a successful login from the PDF-exert app, and when I turn off CA for Sharepoint online, I can successfully add both the Onedrive and Sharepoint source in the PDF-expert app. I've experimented with the "client apps" and selected everything and nothing, but that makes no difference.

Any ideas where to look further?

Here is a picture of my configured CA.

[image: Configured CA]

Note: currently it's one user who uses this, but exempting that user from CA beats the purpose of having CA, so that's not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contact with support and the support team from the PDF-Expert app we discovered that the issue lies with the app.

> As far as we've understood from your logs, your OneDrive account requires MDM support which is not available in PDF Expert app. Our developers already aware of the issue with such accounts so they'll consider adding OneDrive MDM support in the future versions of PDF Expert app.

Now we wait until they make an update to support this.